# How can I check every input element on an AngularJS page, visible or non-visible?

Tags: html, angularjs

For instance, I have a page that has some forms that are directives. I would like to store every input element on the page into a variable, but some of these elements are hidden behind ng-if's.

How can I get these elements regardless of whether or not they are currently visible on the view? Currently I am using

```
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
```

This is ran on the directive that corresponds with the templateHTML below:

```
<div>
  <label>Are you planning to attend a commencement ceremony at the Athens Campus? </label>
  <select id="ceremony" name="ceremony" ng-model="gradCeremony" ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in options" required>
  <option value="">Selection Required</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <label class="control-label" for="regional-ceremony">Are you planning to attend a recognition ceremony at one of the regional campuses?</label>
  <select id="regional-ceremony" ng-model="regionalCeremony" ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in options">
  </select>
</div>

<!-- This one is hidden by default -->
<div ng-if="regionalCeremony">
  <label>Please indicate the regional campus</label>
  <select id="regional-campus-ceremony" ng-model="regionalCeremonyCampus" ng-options="c.code as c.name for c in campuses" required>
    <option value="">Selection Required</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

As you can see, that last option is hidden behind an ng-if. It is not picked up in the array of inputs like I would like it to be.

This code is called with this in the html:

```
<form name="Form" commencement application="application" campuses="campuses" submitting="submitting"></form>
```

Comment: If it's hidden behind an `ng-if`, then it's not in the document.   `ng-show` hides elements. `ng-if` removes them.

Comment: Is there any way to access it like I want when it's behind an ng-if? Also, good information to know, thanks.

Comment: The way to access it like you want is to use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`.  You can't access a dom element that isn't in the dom.

Comment: Okay, thank you. There isn't a way to call the function that gets the elements again when ng-if is triggered?

Comment: You'd have to recall the function manually when something that triggers an `ngIf` is called

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'call the function that gets the elements again'?  When the condition described in the `ng-if` is truthy, its contents are rendered in the DOM; when it isn't, it's not.  (You don't have to do anything manually, the `$digest` handles this for you.)   `ng-show` always renders its contents into the DOM, but uses css to hide or reveal it.